# FormBuilder object casting to object

Tags: angular, object, casting

Does it possible to cast FormBuilder values to into a object model?

```
this.form.value= this.modelObject; -> just simply doesnt work


let objectModel: ObjectModel = new ObjectModel();

objectModel.objecta = "valueA";
objectModel.objectb = "valueB";

this.form = formBuilder.group({

objecta: ['', Validators.required],
objectb: ['', Validators.required],

});
```

how can i cast objectModel to this.form above?

form value able to cast from objectModel and auto populate objecta and objectb value from objectModel into form object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
this.form.patchValue(modelObject); // carefull both object should be the same
```

The form should be set or patched the values. Eg

```
this.form.setValue({
    firstName :  this.modelObject.firstName,
    lastName : this.modelObject.lastName 
})
```

When you use `setValue`, you should give all properties of form. But if you use `patchValue`, you can give all properties or selected properties.

```
this.form.patchValue({
    firstName :  this.modelObject.firstName
    // No need to give lastName
})
```

Comment: Hi i m expecting object casting and not object assignment. Cast means if i have 10 values and can be assigned 1 one line like below. this.form.value = this.modelObject.value

Comment: I updated my answer, please check whether it's useful